# Export encountered errors on following paths

Tags: next.js, next.js13

What is Wrong with this component, I am using `NextJs 14` app router,
on yarn dev server it's running but when I am building the project then get error
Export encountered errors on the following paths:
`quiz -->result-->page.tsx`
this is my folder structure.

```
'use client';

import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';
import Result from './Result';

export default function QuizResultPage() {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const quizId = searchParams?.get('quizId');
  const token = searchParams?.get('token');

  if (!quizId || !token) {
    return <h1>Quiz Result page</h1>;
  }

  return <Result quizId={quizId} token={token} />;
}
```

on yarn dev server it's running but when I am building the project then get an error :

```
Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /(index)/quiz/result/page: /quiz/result
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error adding dynamic imports.
You can try it
Add

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
```

Remove `import Result from './Result';` and add

```
const Result = dynamic(() => import("@/app/quiz/Result"), { ssr: false });
```

read https://nextjs.org/learn-pages-router/seo/improve/dynamic-import-components